# How to determine if a ray intersects a line?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, vectors, computational-geometry, cross-product

I'm trying to determine how you could check if a ray, given an origin and a direction, and a line, given 2 points (Not a line segment) intersect.

Ray: Origin(x,y), direction(x,y)

Line: point1(x,y), point2(x,y)

I thought about doing a case analysis, such as checking if they are parallel, check if the ray is to the left of the line then check the direction etc. but I believe there is a better way to do it involving the cross products.

I'm trying to write a program to do this check, but my issue lies with coming up with a method to perform this check. I'm kind of clueless as to doing an overly complicated case-analysis.

Comment: treat the ray as a line with $x = o + t \cdot d$. (o = origin, d = direction, t = parameter). Solve for the intersection with the line which is given by the points. This will occur at some $t$. If $t\ge0$, they intersect. If $|t|\to \infty$, the ray and the line are parallel.

Comment: Loserman can the ray be treated as a line of indefinite length?

Comment: @samjoe The ray has an origin and a direction, so for example, if the line is a vertical line at point1(0,0),point2(0,1) and the ray originates at origin(1,0) and goes towards direction(2,0) then they won't intersect. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s put some names to things. We have to origin of the ray $O(x_0,y_0)$ and its direction $\mathbf v(x_v,y_v)$. The two points on the line we’ll call $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$. A simple way to proceed is to find the intersection $Q$ of the two *lines* and then compare the direction of $Q-O$ to $\mathbf v$.

Working in homogeneous coordinates, $\overline{P_1P_2}$ is $\mathbf l=(x_1,y_1,1)\times(x_2,y_2,1)$ and the line that contains the ray is $\mathbf m=(x_0,y_0,1)\times(x_v,y_v,0)$. Their intersection is $\mathbf l\times\mathbf m$. If the third element of the result is zero, then the lines are parallel. Otherwise, convert back to Cartesian coordinates by dividing through by this third coordinate to get $Q(x_q,y_q)$. Compute $Q-O$ and compare the sign of a non-zero component of this pair to the corresponding component of $\mathbf v$. If they’re the same, then the intersection lies on the ray.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines through points $z_1,z_2$
and $z_3,z_4$ intersect at a point
($\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$):
\begin{align}
z&=
f_{\times}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=
\frac{
(z_1-z_2)\,(\overline{z_3}\,z_4-\overline{z_4}\,z_3)
-(z_3-z_4)\,(\overline{z_1}\,z_2-\overline{z_2}\,z_1)
}{ 
(z_1-z_2)\,(\overline{z_3}-\overline{z_4})
-(z_3-z_4)\,(\overline{z_1}-\overline{z_2})
}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}
unless the denominator is zero, which is a special case
that need to be treated separately.

If we set $z_1=0$, $z_2=d$ (direction of the ray),
and the endpoints
of given segment $A=z_3,\ B=z_4$,
then  \eqref{1} simplifies to

\begin{align}
z&= 
\frac{d\,(\overline{A}\,B-\overline{B}\,A)}{
d\,(\overline{A}-\overline{B})
-\overline{d}\,(A-B)}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Given that, consider two real numbers $t,\,s$ such that
conditions
\begin{align}
z&=t\cdot d
,\\
\text{along with }\quad
z&=(1-s)\cdot A+s\cdot B
\quad\text{hold}
.
\end{align}

If $t\ge0$ and $s\in[0,1]$ then $z$ is the sought point.

Answer (score 0):

We first find the $y=mx+b$ form of the equation of the line containing the two given points.

For the ray we do two things: we first find the parametric form using the point and direction, and then convert that into a non-parametric form that represents the line that contains the ray.

We represent the ray $$r=\{(x,y): (x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+t(dx, dy), t\ge 0\}$$ where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the origin of the ray and $(dx, dy)$ is the direction. Note that the ray comprises the points corresponding to $t\ge 0$ but if we let $t$ be any real number we get the parametric equation of the line $l_r$ that contains the ray.

Converting $l_r$ into non-parametric form we get $$(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+t(dx,dy)\implies (x,y)=(x_0+tdx, y_0+tdy)\implies\\x=x_0+tdx\\y=y_0+tdy$$

If either $dx=0$ or $dy=0$ then $l_r$ is represented by $x=x_0$ or $y=y_0$, respectively. Note that if both are zero, then we have a point, not a ray.
Otherwise we get $$\frac{x-x_0}{dx}=\frac{y-y_0}{dy}$$

Now we have the equations for two lines we use basic algebra to find their intersection point, if any.

The point of intersection will correspond to some value of $t$ from the parametric representation of the line that contains the ray. If that $t$ is non-negative then the ray and the line intersect, otherwise they don't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a planar situation and cross-products in 2D are just a projection of their 3D normal definitions. This means there are 3 possible definitions considering that in planar situations you not only have in-plane vectors but also have out-of-plane scalars to describe moments (torques) of lines, and rotations. In homogeneous coordinates, this is the third component that is needed.

### Planar Vector Algebra

<sub>I am using ***slanted boldface*** typeface for vector quantities and regular *slanted* typeface for scalar values.</sub>

- `Vector × Vector = Scalar`
  $$\boldsymbol{v}_1 \times \boldsymbol{v}_2 = s_3$$
  $$ \pmatrix{x_1 \\ y_1} \times \pmatrix{x_2 \\ y_2} = x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 $$
- `Vector × Scalar = Vector`
  $$ \boldsymbol{v}_1 \times s_2 = \boldsymbol{v}_3$$
  $$ \pmatrix{x_1 \\ y_1} \times s_2 = \pmatrix{y_1 s_2\\ -x_1 s_2 } $$
- `Scalar × Vector = Vector`
  $$ s_1 \times \boldsymbol{v}_2  = \boldsymbol{v}_3$$
  $$ s_1 \times \pmatrix{x_2 \\ y_2} = \pmatrix{-y_2 s_1\\ x_2 s_1 } $$

In addition to the dot products (for completeness)

- `Vector · Vector = Scalar`
  $$\boldsymbol{v}_1 \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_2 = s_3$$
  $$ \pmatrix{x_1 \\ y_1} \times \pmatrix{x_2 \\ y_2} = x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 $$
- `Vector · Scalar = 0`
  $$ \boldsymbol{v}_1 \cdot s_2 = 0$$
- `Scalar · Vector = 0`
  $$ s_1 \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_2  = 0$$

### Planar Homogeneous Geometry

#### Points

A 2D point is constructed with

$${\bf P}(x,y) = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ 1}$$

but also with every non-zero scalar multiple of the above

$${\bf P}(a,b,c) = \pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c}$$

such that $x = a/c$ and $y=b/c$.

I prefer the general construction using a vector and a scalar to define a point which works well in a programming environment

$$ \mathrm{point}(\boldsymbol{v},s) = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v} \\ s }$$

in order to facilitate not only points from coordinates such as ${\rm point}( \pmatrix{x\\y},\,1)$ but also from the intersection of two lines (to be shown later).

#### Vectors

A vector or displacement is just like point, but the scalar part is zero.

$${\rm vector}( \boldsymbol{v} ) = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v} \\ 0}$$

#### Lines

A line is also constructed from a vector and a scalar (the meaning of which I will explain soon) in a similar fashion to points

$$ \mathrm{line}(\boldsymbol{v},s) = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v} \\ s }$$

The meaning of the components become apparent from the definition of a point $(x,y)$ that belongs to the line

$$  \pmatrix{ v_x \\ v_y \\ s} \cdot \pmatrix{ x \\ y \\ 1} = 0 $$

where $\boldsymbol{v} = (v_x,v_y)$

The above is represents the following equation of a line $(v_x) \,x + (v_y) \, y + (s) = 0$ with the following properties

- Direction of line $$ \boldsymbol{\rm dir} = \frac{ \boldsymbol{v} \times s }{s\, \| \boldsymbol{v} \|} = \pmatrix{ \frac{v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}} \\ - \frac{v_x}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}} }$$
- Distance from origin $$ d = \frac{|s|}{\| \boldsymbol{v} \|} = \tfrac{|s|}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}$$
- Closet point to the origin $$ \boldsymbol{\rm cen} =- \frac{ \boldsymbol{v}\,s }{ \| \boldsymbol{v} \|^2} = \pmatrix{ -\frac{s v_x}{v_x^2+v_y^2} \\ -\frac{s v_y}{v_x^2+v_y^2} }$$

### Intersections

#### Point where Two Lines meet

Use the cross-products defined at the beginning to intersect lines and points

$$  \pmatrix{\boldsymbol{v}_1 \\ s_1 } \times \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v}_2 \\ s_2 }  = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v}_1 \times s_2 + \boldsymbol{s}_1 \times \boldsymbol{v}_2 \\ \boldsymbol{v}_1 \times \boldsymbol{v}_2 } $$

#### Line Joining Two Points

$$  \pmatrix{\boldsymbol{v}_1 \\ s_1 } \times \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v}_2 \\ s_2 }  = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v}_1 \times s_2 + \boldsymbol{s}_1 \times \boldsymbol{v}_2 \\ \boldsymbol{v}_1 \times \boldsymbol{v}_2 } $$

So for example the coordinates of a line defined by a **ray** with origin point $\pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{v} \\ s }$ and direction $\pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{e} \\ 0}$ is

$$  \pmatrix{\boldsymbol{v} \\ s } \times \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{e} \\ 0 }  = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{s} \times \boldsymbol{e} \\ \boldsymbol{v} \times \boldsymbol{e} } $$

The above are the 2D projections of the regular 3D cross-product

$$ \pmatrix{ x_1 \\ y_1 \\ s_1 } \times \pmatrix{ x_2 \\ y_2 \\ s_2} = \pmatrix{ y_1 s_2 - s_1 y_2 \\ s_1 x_2 - x_1 s_2  \\ x_1 y_2 - y_1 x_2 }$$

Depending on how you define your objects, either with a 2D vector and a scalar, or with a 3D vector (or 3 components) you can use either the 2D version or the 3D version just above here.